# How to assure equal chances of being hired?

Tags: recruitment, equality

I'm in the process of creating a company, and one of the points I care a lot about is equality of chances, a candidate for a job shouldn't have less chance to be recruited because of his/her ethnicity or gender.

Whoever I intend to take as a recruiter later, I know he/she is a human being, with personal opinions which can be kept to him/herself and affect the choice of an appropriate candidate.

How can we be sure that candidates are given equal chances of being hired in a company ? Or at least minimize the risks.

Comment: Anonymous applications could be an interesting tool for you.

Comment: @Artery I was thinking maybe "chat interviews", might even allow us to see a candidate's grammar level

Comment: @S.Hochberg So you're going to discriminate against immigrants then?

Comment: @Lilienthal Could you explain please ? I don't see where I talked about discriminating anyone, I just ask for a way to avoid discrimination from recruiters while in a hiring process.

Comment: @S.Hochberg By having "chat interviews", you will hinder those who do no have a firm grasp on your language, particularly immigrants

Comment: @JohnHC I see your point, it's not a good solution then.

Comment: Be mindful of what skills you actually demand. "Excellent written and spoken english skills" may sound nice on an ad, but is hardly necessary for all roles in a company, and by screening for those, you're unfairly disadvantaging people who don't have them but might otherwise be perfectly qualified.

Comment: @Magisch The trouble (or paradox) is that while hiring I know the answers of a candidate are equally important as his/her resume. If it wasn't recruiters would not make any interviews and the hiring process would be done by just looking at resumes. The idea then would be to find a way to recruit without checking his/her grammar...But that would require a face-to-face interview and we're back at the beginning.

Comment: @S.Hochberg You're always going to have to interview people face to face. You can never completly eliminate bias. But being mindful of it and eliminating it in the first screening stage can go a long way.

Comment: @JohnHC language ability is definitely something you need to establish though, I have worked with people who were good programmers but who struggled to follow instructions correctly due to their grasp of english.

Comment: Don't go too far the other way. If you get 10 male applicants and 1 female applicants, accept that it is very unlikely the female applicant will get the job, statistically. If you attempt to create an equality of outcome then you've gone too far the other direction. Don't consider gender when making a decision.

Comment: @SLC The goal is not to have 50% men 50% women, the goal is to be sure that if someone is employed it is because they were the best fit and not because of their sex or ethnicity. It can still lead to 40% men 60% women or the other way around.

Comment: As John said, I was referring to the fact that if you're explicitly looking at grammar level, you're automatically going to be discriminating against non-native speakers. Magisch correctly pointed out that you're always going to have bias in an interview process: you're there to find the best candidate after all. Eliminating bias is impossible (we recently had another question on this topic I think) and your focus should be on establishing criteria that a candidate should meet while consciously avoiding considering criteria that you cannot or should not factor into a hiring decision.

Comment: Take a bucket, put candidate names in papers, put the papers in the bucket and pick one randomly. That's the best way to give them equal chances. Even running a test will favor people good at taking tests, if that is a quality you look for, then probably that is the way to go. It is a selection process, your best odds are to focus on solutions they can deliver (out from a multiple choice test, perhaps?) and use a grading for choosing top performers, that is warranty of not that much, but gives you a sense of achievement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You correctly identified the main crux of the issue. Regardless of your intentions, you or anyone you delegate hiring to will have (sometimes unconscious) biases in either direction. Thus a hiring decision you make can never be *perfectly* equal.

You can however take some steps to ensure a relatively unbiased hiring process:

- During initial screening, have an assistant or scretary or a software you buy strip out the name, nationality, gender and other directly identifying characteristics from the applications and replace them with an applicant id before you get to see them. That way you can rule out unconscious bias in the first screening step by withholding information that *should not matter* from yourself or any recruiters you pass the resumes to.
- Only advertise for and screen for skills you really need. These days, a whole bunch of jobs just include boilerplate traits like "great at teamwork and excellent written and spoken english skills". Check if you really need those or if you're just listing them because you had space to fill and it sounds good. You don't need someone with excellent written and spoken english skills for a machine operator role, for instance. This also ties in with your comment, make sure the applicant really needs those skills to succeed in their role before filtering for them.
- Do not request information from applicants that you don't need. You don't need to know the marital status or the gender of someone until the interview stage. At the interview, don't ask questions about things that you don't need to know, not even for the sake of smalltalk. Any extraneous and unnecessary personal information you have about an applicant can unconsciously bias you or the recruiter, and if the information is unnecessary to have, there is no need to invite that risk for literally no benefit.